# Why LegacyFormHelper in FOSUserBundle removed

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

we have a Symofny 2.8 application, and on serval places we use the LegacyFormHelper from the OS\UserBundle\Util\LegacyFormHelper.

It seems, that in the actual update this class has removed, and I wonder why.

So actually, I'm looking for a possibility to use a RepeatedType in a FormType, which is acutally coded like

```
->add('plainPassword', LegacyFormHelper::getType('Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType'), array(
                    'type' => LegacyFormHelper::getType('Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType'),
                    'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
                    'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password', 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Passwort')),
                    'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
                    'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
                    'required' => false
                ))
```

And now we want to code that without the LegacyFormHelper.

Has Somebody an idea?

Regards
Thomas

Answer (score 6):

And somtimes I can answer my own questions ;-)

I simply do

```
->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
                    'type' => PasswordType::class,
                    'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
                    'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password', 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Passwort')),
                    'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
                    'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
                    'required' => false
                ))
```

So if somebody has as similar problem with the LegacyFormHelper, the solution is easy!